# Upload file to aws S3 bucket using absolute path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to upload files from Express ejs to AWS s3 bucket I am successful in doing so but when I am trying to select files from other directory or folder other than where my index.js is it doesn't accept the file and throw error file not found.

**index.js**

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer  = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: ''
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true})); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 



const uploadS3 = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: '',
    metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname})
    },
    key: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
  })
});
```

**test.ejs**

```html
<html>
  <form method="post" action="/upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</html>
```

**route.js**

```
var fileupload = require('../../common/service/file-upload');
//some code in between 

app.post('/upload', fileupload.uploadS3.single('file'),(req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
});
```

Comment: can you add the code how to you selects the file?

Comment: i have added test.ejs is my express js file from which <input type="file"> i am selecting file

Comment: whenever you are uploading the files you need to add attribute to form enctype="multipart/form-data". .then it will work.I recommends you to use multer-s3 package to upload file on aws.https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3

Comment: Off-topic: DONT!!! Hardcode your Credentials, use environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you are uploading the files you need to add attribute to form enctype="multipart/form-data". .then it will work.
to upload files to s3 use multer-s3 package which is simple to configure
Refrence : https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3

so your test.ejs file will be like this

```
   <html>
     <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" />
      <const/form>
   </html>
```

and index.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const multer = require('multer')
    const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')



    const app = express();
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: //aws access key ,
        secretAccessKey: //aws secret key
    });

        const upload = multer({
          storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: 'some-bucket',
            metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
              cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
            },
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
              cb(null, Date.now().toString())
            }
          })
        })



    app.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
      res.json({
        message: "File uploaded to S3"
      });
    });
```

Comment: hi , when i add app.post('', upload.single('file') in my route.js file its shows typerror cannot read propert single of undefined.

Comment: Have you defined upload,S3 parameters as per specified?.can you show your code how you have added?

Comment: hello , i have added the route.js file and update index.js file .

Answer (score 0):

Man, how could Express read client's file by path? The files are uploaded / sent in the POST request.

Use some body parser that support `multipart/form-data` file upload, like [mutler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), to parse the file from the request & upload it to S3.

In example...

**html**

```html
<html>
  <!-- don't forget enctype parameter -->
  <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</html>
```

**node server** using [AWS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) manually

```js
const multer = require('multer'),
      AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
      S3 = new AWS.S3({
        ...
      });

router.post('/', multer().single('file'), (req, res) => {
  // debug req.file
  console.log(req.file);
  
  S3.upload({
    Bucket: '...',
    Key: req.file.originalname, 
    Body: req.file.buffer
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json({
      message: "File uploaded to S3"
    });
  });
});
```

**node server** using [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3)

```js
const multer = require('multer'),
      multerS3 = require('multer-s3'),
      AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
      S3 = new AWS.S3({
        ...
      });

let upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: '...',
    key: (req, file, cb) 
      => cb(null, file.originalname), // or whatever Key you like
  })
});

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "File uploaded to S3"
  });
});
```

Comment: why not use multer-s3 package which was specially for uploading file to aws s3 bucket.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3
which is simple to configure

Comment: i am not an expert but these will work without body-parser it through undefined error whenever i try to console.log to know the file name selected

Comment: he added metadata parameter wrong way & not added key parameter. in configuring the multer. @rohan also take reference from this https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3 –